# Ruby ActiveRecord getting a range up to last entry?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

Suppose I have 100 entries in my database, my mobile application has an infinite listview which queries the database for the entries.

The application displays items in batches of 15, once a user reaches the end of the 15 items, the application will query for the next 15 items. This means that there will be a remained of 10 items to make a total 100 items.

I have tried looking at some of the ActiveRecord's method such as `find`:

```
# Find the clients with primary keys 1 and 10.
clients = Client.find([var, var+14]) # var integer is provided by GET request.
# => [#<Client id: 1, first_name: "Lifo">, #<Client id: 10, first_name: "Ryan">]
```

However, it is noted that `The find method will raise an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exception unless a matching record is found for all of the supplied primary keys.`

How then would I go about fetching the last 10 items to show on screen? Also, is it possible to get ActiveRecord to return a value when there are no items in range so I can display an `all items shown` message?

Comment: `Client.where(id: (var..var +14))` should do it. Although I would probably recommend `Client.limit(15).offset(var).order(:id)` which will order by id and select the next  15 based on the offset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Client.offset(15 * iteration).first(15)
```

is what I would recommend here. Then iteration should be 0 for the first 15, 1 the second time you refresh your list. Of course you can adjust the way you compute your offset.

You might want to specify a `order` though, to keep it consistent.

Comment: I'll try this. Just to inquire, how does ActiveRecord format the return values? Json?

Comment: @Carrein they will be returned as instances of the `Client` class as you have shown in your post

Answer (score 0):

```
Client.limit(15).offset(var).order(:id)
```

This is what I would suggest as to the best of my knowledge shouldn't throw you any errors