# Ruby ActiveRecord retrieving new inserted records in batches?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, dart

This pertains to my previous [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51155282/ruby-activerecord-getting-a-range-up-to-last-entry).

I am able to get batches of records from ActiveRecord using the following query:

```
Client.offset(15 * iteration).first(15)
```

I'm running into an issue whereby a user inputs a new record.

Say there are 100 records, and batches are of 15.
The first 6 iterations (90 records) and the last iteration (10 records) works. However, if a new entry comes in (making it a total of 101 records), the program fails as it will either:

a) If the iteration counter is set to increment, it will query for records beyond the range of 101, resulting in nothing being returned.

b) If the iteration counter is modified to increment only when an entire batch of 15 items are complete, then repeat the last 14 items plus 1 new item.

How do i go about getting newly posted records?

**dart code:**

```
_getData() async {
    if (!isPerformingRequest) {
      setState(() {
        isPerformingRequest = true;
      });

      //_var represents the iteration counter - 0, 1, 2 ...
      //fh is a helper method returning records in List<String>
      List<String> newEntries = await fh.feed(_var);

      //Count number of returned records.
      newEntries.forEach((i) => _count++);

      if (newEntries.isEmpty) {
        ..
        }
      } else {

        //if number of records is 10, increment _var to go to the next batch of 10.
        if(_count == 10) {
          _var++;
          _count = 0;
        }
        //but if count is not 10, stay with the same batch (but previously counted/display records will be shown again)
      }

      setState(() {
        items.addAll(newEntries);
        isPerformingRequest = false;
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Go ahead and show us some code for what you are trying to do.

Comment: With 101 records, try in console `User.offset(90).limit(15)` and `User.offset(105).limit(15)`. The first should return 11 records and the second an empty array. If works like that maybe you are iterating 7 times not handling the empty array? This is my guess, but better you post the error message if I'm wrong.